Image reveal on hover does not work in Safari
I used a a cool js script to have a creative ang engaging section on a new client site where the user can hover over a word and a image will then reveal itself. I found a CodePen that does exactly what I want.
I integrated this code into my Shopify site and it all works well in Chrome, Firefox and Edge.
Yet, it doesn't in Safari. There are weird glitches and mostly the first image pops up but then sometime does not hide again on mouse out. At best you have to open the codepen in safari and check it out for yourself.
The script uses a mouseover and mousemove and mouseleave Eventlistener to replace the image src="" when the mouse hovers. Again, this script works perfect in all the other browsers but not in safari.
Does anyone know how to fix that?
I already tried to replace const with var and several more small detail changes based on some comments I found on StackOverflow but nothing really worked.
Code Snippet
( also on CodePen )


const items = document.querySelectorAll('.item')
const image = document.querySelector('img')

items.forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
    imageData = e.target.getAttribute('data-image')
    console.log(imageData)
    e.target.style.zIndex = 99
    image.setAttribute('src', imageData)
  })
  el.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
    image.style.top = e.clientY + 'px'
    image.style.left = e.clientX + 'px'
  })
  el.addEventListener('mouseleave', (e) => {
    e.target.style.zIndex = 1
    image.setAttribute('src', '')
  })
})
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Belleza');
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #ffebd5;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  li {
    font-family: 'Belleza', sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px black;
    color: transparent;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    z-index: 1;
  }
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30%;
  object-fit: contain;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 10;
}
<img src="">
<ul>
  <li class="item" data-image="https://ct112013.files.wordpress.com/2013/07/pasteeel.jpg">WOMAN</li>
  <li class="item" data-image="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/1a/e9/ff/1ae9ff68eddb75113cc797f1324515b9--color-coordination-reiss.jpg">MAN</li>
  <li class="item" data-image="http://www.todaysparent.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Mint1.jpg">KID</li>
</ul>




Interesting. I tried to replace mouseleave with mouseout but it still doesn't work in safari.
